# Present or confer?

Tags: word-choice

For example, which one is more accurate in the following context?
1) The government presented a medal to him
2) The government conferred a medal to him

And in general, what is the difference between the two words?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a start, it's 'conferred a medal *on* him', meaning that an official decision was made that he was worthy of receiving an award. 'Presented' is more of a reference to the actual ceremony.

Comment: So, if referring to an event of the conferring ceremony, we should say, for instance: "The PM presented a medal to him"?

Comment: Yes. The government, or an organisation, confers a decoration or award on somebody. A dignitary presents it to them.

Answer (score -1):

presenting means gifting, confer means gifting with honor

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).